# Add primary key column in SQL table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am student of RDBMS.

I have very basic question let say I have one existing Table in SQL server. What will be script to alter table.

- Drop Column 'RowId' if exist.
- Drop contraint if exist.
- Add one new column 'RowId' into table.
- Make this column as primary key.
- Autoincrement type int.

Comment: Dropping a column and removing a primary key constraint are different things. Your first line is therefor not clear. Can you also post your attempt at this and explain where you are stuck?

Comment: What do you really want?

Comment: Do you not want to preserve "old" RowId until the entire sequence is complete? Is this "old" RowId expected to be IDENTITY too? Why replace a column with one of the same name?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005 or newer, you could use this script:

```
-- drop PK constraint if it exists
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.key_constraints WHERE type = 'PK' AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.YourTable') AND Name = 'PK_YourTable')
   ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
   DROP CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable
GO

-- drop column if it already exists
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE Name = 'RowId' AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.YourTable'))
    ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable DROP COLUMN RowId
GO

-- add new "RowId" column, make it IDENTITY (= auto-incrementing)
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable 
ADD RowId INT IDENTITY(1,1)
GO

-- add new primary key constraint on new column   
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable 
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (RowId)
GO
```

Of course, this script may still fail, if other tables are referencing this `dbo.YourTable` using foreign key constraints onto the pre-existing `RowId` column...

**Update:** and **of course**, anywhere I use `dbo.YourTable` or `PK_YourTable`, you have to replace those placeholder with the **actual** table / constraint names from your own database (you didn't mention what they were, in your question.....)

Comment: Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The object 'PK_tempTable' is dependent on column 'RowId'.

Comment: Well, then include a `ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable DROP CONSTRAINT PK_tempTable` - is the PK called something else than the table name??? If your constraint is not called `PK_YourTable` , you have to **adapt my script** accordingly, of course!

Comment: I think this is not in constraint it is showing in key folder

Comment: I checked that OBJECT_ID('dbo.tempTable') is not returning correct objectid

Comment: @SOFUser: yes - of course - it's a primary **KEY** after all - but that's still a table **constraint**

Answer (score 9):

Note: this answer was added before questions update

- Add new column (note: you can only have one IDENTITY column per table)
- Drop old primary key
- Add new primary key
- Drop old column if needed

Sample script:

```
CREATE TABLE whatever (
     OldPKColumn uniqueidentifier NOT NULL, 
     CONSTRAINT PK_whatever PRIMARY KEY (OldPKColumn)
    )

ALTER TABLE whatever
    ADD RowId int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1);

ALTER TABLE whatever
    DROP CONSTRAINT PK_whatever;

ALTER TABLE whatever WITH CHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_whatever PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (RowId);

ALTER TABLE whatever
    DROP COLUMN oldPKcolumn;
```

And a random thought... are you trying to reset an IDENTITY column?
If so, then use [DBCC CHECKIDENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx)

Comment: @SOF User: I've a better idea. Ask a better question and don't be rude. You changed the question while I was answering, and I asked for clarification in a comment.

Answer (score 8):

*Just a comment to improve these great answers (can't use comments yet - I'm one reputation point away from that privilege) and as future reference for myself:*

A new IDENTITY (autonumber) column can be added and made the primary key in a single statement as well:

> ALTER TABLE [TableName] ADD [ColumnName] int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY;

I prefer not to bother with constraint names when it doesn't help.

You can specify *seed* (and *increment*) values between parantheses after the `IDENTITY` keyword.