# SQL Server : set primary key without dropping table and content

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to set the primary key and auto increment on a SQL Server table without dropping and recreating the table, and losing all it's data?

Comment: Any idea how? Any pointers would be much appreciated Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158564/add-primary-key-column-in-sql-table

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862385/sql-server-add-auto-increment-primary-key-to-existing-table

Answer (score 6):

Yes of course! You just add a new column, and it an `INT IDENTITY` and add a primary key constraint to it:

```
 ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
 ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL

 ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
 ADD CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable PRIMARY KEY (ID)
```

Answer (score 3):

If there is an existing primary key, you must first drop it:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.key_constraints
           WHERE type = 'PK' AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('MyTable')
           AND Name = 'PK_MyTable')
    ALTER TABLE MyTable DROP CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable
```

If you are adding a column to be used as a primary key, then you can simply add it:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD MyKey INT IDENTITY
```

Then, you can set this column as your table's primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable PRIMARY KEY(MyKey)
```